# Codeigniter- admin add data for specific user and user see admin inputed data when he logged in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've just completed user and admin signup and login system in codeigniter. I have two table `massuser` and `meal`. in the meal table admin add data for users and in the massuser table is recorded data when user sign up. and I am able to show specific user signup data into the view by session but I am not able to show admin inputed data in the same view. I have tried many times but I can't. please help me?

**Meal Table structure**

```
**================================
    id---- username----meal---date
===============================**
```

**Massuser Table structure**

```
============================================================
id----fullname----username----password----email----regdate
============================================================
```

**Controller**

```
public function mymeals()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $data['results'] = $this->usermodel->get_meal($username);
            $this->load->view('public/profile/profile',$data);
        }else{
            echo "No results";

        }

    }
```

**model**

```
public function get_meal($username)
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('meal');
        $this->db->where('username', $user);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $query;
    }
```

**view**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Meal</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
            foreach($results as $meal):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $meal->date;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $meal->meal;?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share your tables structure also.

Comment: How are you inserting the data in meal table, manually? What is the type of column username in meal table? And in code, you are getting username from session, username of admin or logged in user?

Comment: at this time I am inserting data in the meal table, manually. meal table username column is exactly match with `massuser` `username` and type `VARCHAR`.suppose meal table `username = moneyhub` and `massuser username = moneyhub` I am getting logged in user username form session. Thank you @sumit

Answer (score 0):

It could be that in your model you are accessing session data.

Do you still get the problem if you used the actual passed variable?

Try

```
public function get_meal($username) {
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('meal')
             ->where('username', $username);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```